# how can I use any Ethiopic/Ge'ez writing in Latex?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I am a new Latex user. I just started to use it for writing articles and monographs. I am particularly interested to write papers with a mixed language fonts (Ethiopic/Ge'ez and English). With a lot of suggestions from the XeLatex to using fontspec, I gathered I could write Ethiopic/Ge'ez fonts in an English main text. However, in my many futile attempts, nothing comes through! So, I was wondering if anyone could help me in creating a basic MWE for both languages? 
Here is one of my many attempts that failed to work for me (resulting in just a bunch of questions marks):

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Abyssinica SIL}


\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{geez}

\newfontfamily{\geezfont}[Script=Ethiopic]{Abyssinica SIL}

\newenvironment{geez}
  {\geezfont}
  {}



\begin{document}

\section*{Section about Tigrinya}

\begin{geez}
እስመ 
\end{geez}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dowloaded the font as a zip file from

https://software.sil.org/abyssinica/download/

and put the main ttf font in the current directory, then this minor modification of your example worked producing this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf}


\setmainlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{geez}

\newfontfamily{\geezfont}[Script=Ethiopic]{AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf}

\newenvironment{geez}
  {\geezfont}
  {}



\begin{document}

\section*{Section about Tigrinya}

\begin{geez}
እስመ 
\end{geez}

\end{document}
```

but this is using the same font for Latin script and the geez section, and causes some warnings that bold is not available. 
Perhaps you don't want to set this font as `\setmainfont`  if the main text is English, but perhaps you do to get consistent fonts even if it is more restricted.

---

simpler lower level example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


TEST:
\font\zz="[./AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf]" at 20pt
\zz
እስመ 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response David Charlisle. I have a system-wide Abyssinica SIL but with the main rtf you just used, I am getting the "font-not-found" response when attempting to compose. I tried to re-install the font again, just incase, but I'm still getting the same response ... ??? (invisible Ge'ez fonts).

Comment: debugging system font lookup remotely is tricky:) what operating system and tex system do you have? you could try the filename rather than the internal font name as I have and also as a test do as I did here and simply put the ttf file in the same directory as the tex document, if that works we know it's just a font search path issue

Comment: I am using macOS High Sierra (MacBook Pro mid 2015) and have TexShop version 4.44 running. How do I tell it to use the filename (opposed to the internal font name)? I have checked the directory to make sure the font name and the tex document to be under the same directory, but still getting the same (with the ttf ''font-not-found'' and with SIL "???") result. Any other possible avenues to explore?

Comment: My naive understanding of the typesetting cost me a lot of time to figure out the issue. I have been rereading the fontspec documentation and other polyglossia hoping that the answer I am looking for might be somewhere there. However, I came to understand that you cannot directly input/write every script other than Latin or an adaptation of it on the MWE. A transliteration or conversion is required! I found this after I recognized that the Ge'ez word I was typing in Abyssinica SIL turned into a bunch of question marks after a couple rerun of the typeset anew.

Comment: I was expecting a Verbatim command/environment would work for some Ge'ez texts but that still wouldn't resolve the issue. It appears that XeLatex or LuaLatex are dependent on conversion of Ge'ez Unicode into Latin and vice versa by fonspec. So, now I have to figure out how to type Ge'ez with Abyssinica SIL with the keyboard layout I have and input that Latin-based Ge'ez Unicode into the MWE so that fonspec would do the conversion. With that what I initially proposed or what David Carlisle suggested would work perfectly.

Comment: What is still not possible is, to cut and paste Ge'ez text within the Latex environment (unless the text is copied as a picture of some sort).

Comment: from my vantage point, if I cut and paste the Ge'ez text, it doesn't typeset it as such because, what I see is (after I close and reopen the file) is a bunch of ???.

Comment: only when I use the latin "masTA" (or a version of it) and typeset it, do I get the actual Ge'ez word. Otherwise, the route I have been taking and wanting to implement "writing Ge'ez in Latex" with the MWE I adopted and initiated in the first place didn't work for me.

Comment: @KGG you are doing something wrong, but not giving enough information to say what. You should be able to use exactly the document I post above which has `እስመ ` in the source. Do you get any warnings in the log if you use the document from this answer?

Comment: you're absolutely right there is something wrong with my MWE, although I couldn't be able to figure that out.

Comment: Here are the issues: (i) if I use the AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf to set the main font, I get "font-not-found"  error (or the font "AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf" cannot be found); (ii) if I use the Abyssinica SIL to set the main font, XeLatex composes but the outcome turns out to be a bunch of question marks ("???") including the one in the source code; (iii) if I use the "GeezTypeNet" (another font I adopted for a Ge'ez keyboard purpose), XeLatex composes and the outcome turns out be correct, but in that case I have to transliterate (input "Xsmâ" in the source code so that I would get እስመ).

Comment: @KGG oh the transliteration was using a different font, that explains it! I could not guess how that could possibly happen. For the font not found errors then as a test you should be able to do as I did here and put the ttf file in the same folder as the document, if it doesn't find i then then something really strange is happening.

Comment: show the log you get with _exactly_  the document that I post above, when `AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf` is in the current directory

Comment: Aha, it appears that there is no AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf in the font book, I just noticed; when I re-run the AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf on the same file directory as the Tex (Desktop), it turns out GeezTypeNet is automatically overriding it. Would that be the issue? Otherwise, I couldn't be able to see it in the font menu.

Comment: As I have said before start with specifying _the file name_  using exactly the form I used here. that avoids issues with clashing internal font names. If you get that working then you can look to getting the font names to work.

Comment: (I understand this is a lot of back and forth and apologies for that but) If I couldn't be able run the font file, how do I specify the file name? Also, if Abyssinica SIL is the same family font with AbyssinicaSIL-Regular why is that the tex environment only fixated with the latter?

Comment: @KGG two completely different lookups are used. If you specify a filename as I did here then the tex filename searching is used to find a file of that name. If you use an internal font name like `Abyssinica SIL`  then the system font searching is used (fontconfig on linux or windows) I really can't help with the Mac font searching I don't have a mac, but if you use the file name then it works on all systems the same way. Just forget it is a font. unpack the zip file and put the file `AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf` with your document as you would a tex file or image file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification David Carlisle! Like you suggested, I unpacked the zip file and placed it under the same directory with the tex document, and then I run the MWE form you just modified, but unfortunately the result is the same as I mentioned above - "font-not-found" error. No idea how AbssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf would be used temporarily as a font so that tex would search for it?! Something is wrong with the internal fonts in my Mac; perhaps I will get rid of the original font and see reinstalling anew would resolve it

Comment: @KGG I put a second lower level example into the answer that does not use fontspec or polyglossia, make sure the .ttf file (not the zip) is next to the document

Comment: I get "Font \zz=[./AbyssinicaSIL-Regular at 20 pt not loadable" error ...It seems that ttf file is particularly incompatible with Mac though, even though they say in the documentation it works better with Windows 10 and Linux (as well as current Mac 10 and above versions).

Comment: I'll get some mac users to look...

Comment: Try if lualatex can find the font with `\font\zz={file:AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf} `

Comment: @KGG Use the following  for the font on a Mac: `\newfontfamily{\geezfont}[Script=Ethiopic]{Abyssinica SIL}`  Typically the name that XeTeX looks for is the same name that will display if you look at the font inside Fontbook.app but without any "Regular/Bold/Italic" etc. designation. So in Fontbook the font displays as `Abyssinica SIL Regular`, so use everything up to the Regular part (including spaces.)  This is with the font installed in `/Library/Fonts` (the regular place for system fonts.)

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer thanks for your response; yes, LuaLaTex may compile the AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf (if I place ttf file with the tex document under the same directory) even if the font is not available in the FontBook. Strange! With XeLaTex it doesn't compile at all (font not-found error emerges)

Comment: @Alan Munn Thanks for your response. If you see what David Carlisle and I have exchanged above (know it's very long discussion) the issue with that is that the Ge'ez text either doesn't come out as normal (just a bunch of ??? pops up) or "font-not-found" error emerges

Comment: @KGG did you try with the Script= version Alansugested (I pinged him in chat as an experienced mac user to look over this thread, but good luck I'm out the remaining issues seem mac specific and I can't help)

Comment: Thanks David for your help and for pinging in experienced Mac users in to the discussion! The issue with that suggestion still remains though

Comment: and does lualatex find the font if you don't place it in the same folder? Does lualatex find it if you use `{name:AbyssinicaSIL}` instead of the file name? If yes what does the log say about the location of the font?

Comment: @KGG I'm not sure how much more I can help then, since it definitely works for me (OS 10.12.6/TL 2019) and also for egreg (who is more up to date on both OS and TL).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer it appears that the font directory doesn't seem to matter with lualatex but in the log there are two paths for the font location: /library/fonts/AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf and /library/fonts/AbyssinicaSIL-R.ttf . It is strange that the XeLaTex doesn't locate either in the system

Comment: the second font sounds odd. Try what happens if you remove it. (xelatex is much more pickier than lualatex and fontconfig doesn't make it easier.)

Comment: @AlanMunn and Ulrike Fischer under what circumstance does the internal font conflict arise? I seem to having a conflict in fonts as every time I re-run the Abyssinica SIL anew I find an installation error "proceed with caution" and after I hit install anyway, it directly redirects to GeezTypeNet (another font I use to type Ge'ez text) in the font book. Also after closing the console and reopening it the Ge'ez text in the source code vanishes resulting in a bunch of questions marks. Any idea?

Comment: I have no mac, I'm on windows. I have no idea how font installation works on mac.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer it's strange.I only see Abyssinica SIL, though, in the font book...the second path seems false

Comment: I would put more trust in the log of lualatex than in what ever your system is showing you.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer the issue is I don't seem to figure out why lualatex doesn't make the Ge'ez font visible on the pdf outcome

Comment: well if lualatex finds a faulty font (and this R.ttf looks quite suspicious) then everything can happen. Check in the log-file if it complains about missing chars.

Comment: something bizarre is definitely going on with the fonts in my system. I just get rid of some of the Abyssinica font files and lualatex still compiles and finds the path  /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-regular, which I have no idea where my local directory is...perhaps fontconfig on Mac maybe helpful here

Answer (score 0):

Currently Polyglossia has no support for Ge’ez, but it has experimental support for Amharic, which is not so distant.

If your document has only small pieces in Ge’ez, you don't even need to add the support for the language and the following should suffice.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainlanguage{english}

\newfontface{\geezfont}{AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf}

\newenvironment{geez}
  {\geezfont}
  {}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section about Tigrinya}

Text \begin{geez}
እስመ
\end{geez}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Quite likely you shouldn't set Abyssinica SIL as the main font.

If you need language support, do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{amharic}

\newfontface{\amharicfont}{AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf}

\newenvironment{geez}
  {\amharic}
  {\endamharic}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section about Tigrinya}

Text \begin{geez}
እስመ
\end{geez}

\end{document}
```

but adjustments to the language setup should be made.

**Note.** I loaded the font with the explicit file. If you have installed it system-wide, then

```latex
\newfontface{\geezfont{Abyssinica SIL}
```

should be good.

Comment: Thank you @egreg for your response. Unfortunately I am still getting the same ??? marks with or without setting the new language to Amharic and with the Abyssinica SIL. I have a substantial Ge'ez text on-and-off running in the paper and I'd like to create enabling environment for both languages (English and Ge'ez).